# При старте activity скрывать клавиатуру, а по клику на любой EditText показывать

Tags: java, android

Перерыл много свойств, но все не то.

Необходимо при старте `activity` скрывать клавиатуру, а по клику на любой `EditText` показывать.

Использую `NavigationDrawer`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"

        android:text="@string/fion"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fiontext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" "
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fionuri"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

        android:text="@string/adrespropiski"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/naselpun"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/naselpunkt"/>

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/naspunkt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" "
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/adres_ul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/adres"/>

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/ulica"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" "
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phonetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/dom"/>

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/dom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:inputType="phone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/email"/>

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/emailfild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=""
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mesag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/messag"/>

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/mesages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="1000"
        android:hint="введите ваше сообщение"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

в манифесте прописал

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

При запуске клавиатура скрыта, на первом edittext курсор мигает но по нажатию на первый же edittext клавиатура ен показывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать у EditText:

```
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
```